# SQL GroupBy on String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

All I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm trying to group on + count all occurrences of a string which is part of larger string.

Columns look like the following:

```
ColumnA
DomainA\Value
DomainB\Value
DomainXX\Value
DomainABC\Value
```

I was going to do something along the lines to pull the domain value

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin))-1
FROM 
    malign.pluser01 AS PL01
```

Then based on the results count the occurrences, using a `GROUP BY`.

But this returns an error when converting the varchar value to data type int. Running the `LEFT` or `CHARINDEX` function individually works fine, but not together. I'm not sure if this will give me the desired result that I'm after anyway.

What I would like to end up is the following :

```
Domain       Count
Domain A     10
Domain B     20
Domain XX    15
DomainABC    22
```

The Domain Information is held at the beginning of the sting. Is this actually possible or not - what's the best way to do this.

I have managed to find a way around this now.. Only question I have is why is the match pulls values that don't have a '\' in the string, how can I ignore these.

```
SELECT COUNT(pl01.pluser01id) As USERCOUNT 
,(LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin +'\')-1)) As Domain
FROM table1.pluser01 AS PL01
GROUP BY (LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin +'\')-1))
ORDER BY USERCOUNT DESC
```

Which Give me the following results

```
USERCOUNT   DOMAIN
12          DOMAINA 
20          DOMAINB
25          DOMAINXX
1           usera
1           userb
```

and so on..

I want to drop the single entries

Comment: The minus 1 is in the wrong place.  LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin))-1 shoud read LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin) -1)

Comment: Just noticed if I drop the '-1' on the SELECT LEFT command it returns results but includes the 'blackslash' which I don't really want.. So as the CHARINDEX is return a -1 for some of the values I think this  where it may be failing. Any idea how I can ignore them.

Comment: LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin) -1) gives me an Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT of SUBSTING function

Comment: Found the following, which has given me the desired result of match the domain. SELECT LEFT(pl01.plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',pl01.plauthlogin +'\')-1)

Comment: Not sure I'm approaching this right.. How do I count and group the results of all the domains.

Comment: what do you mean by `group the results of all the domains` - what's desired final output?

Answer (score 0):

Move the bracket:

```
LEFT(plauthlogin, CHARINDEX('\',plauthlogin)-1)
```

You are currently doing `LEFT(col, expr) - 1`; you want `LEFT(col, expr - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your question

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (Domain varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Domain)
VALUES
    ('Domain A\10'),
    ('Domain B\20'),
    ('Domain XX\15'),
    ('DomainABC\22')
;


select SUBSTRING(Domain,0,CHARINDEX('\',Domain))Domain,
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(Domain),0,(CHARINDEX('\',reverse(Domain))))) from @Table1
```

Comment: That seems quite a convoluted solution considering the problem is just a misplaced bracket...

Comment: yeah he mentioned in question what my expected output based on that I have given full answer has SO question is  pretty unclear @MarcGravell

Answer (score 0):

The -1 is misplaced in your original query.

I've written the below to illustrate how you can extract the values you need.  Hopefully this query will highlight the techniques you need.

This query will split your field using \ as a delimiter.  I've used a sub query to return the separators position, as this is easier to read.  But you could just as easily do this in one query.

Example

```
/* Create a sample table to experiment with.
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        Value    VARCHAR(25)
    )
;

/* Populate it.
 */
INSERT INTO @sample    
    (
        Value
    )
VALUES
    ('DomainA\1'),
    ('DomainB\2'),
    ('DomainC\3'),
    ('DomainD\4')
;

/* Using the seperator position 
 * return the domain name and 
 * it's value.
 */
SELECT
    LEFT(Value, Seperator -1),
    RIGHT(Value, LEN(Value) - Seperator)
FROM
    (
        /* This sub query returns the position of the \ seperator.
         * It's main prupose is to avoid retyping CHARINDEX several times.
         */
        SELECT
            Value,
            CHARINDEX('\', Value)    AS Seperator
        FROM
            @Sample
    ) AS r
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Value always will be at the end and it is 2 digit only then you can try this,

```
CREATE TABLE BoardmanTable 
(
    ColumnA VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO BoardmanTable (ColumnA)
VALUES
    ('Domain A\10'),
    ('Domain B\20'),
    ('Domain XX\15'),
    ('DomainABC\22')

SELECT LEFT(ColumnA ,CHARINDEX('\' ,ColumnA)-1)
      ,RIGHT(ColumnA ,2) Count
FROM   BoardmanTable AS PL01
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it now... 
Used a HAVING statement after the GROUP BY. I've got exactly what I want.. Thanks ALL